# weird Java serialization logs after upgrading from Java 6 to 8

Tags: java, serialization

I have an application running on JBoss 4.2.3 with Java 6. We are in the process of migrating to Java 8. After I made all the necessary compilation changes and deployments, the application works fine, but I started getting a **LOT** of the following DEBUG level logging:

> 15:37:07,422 DEBUG [serialization] ObjectInputFilter ALLOWED: class
>   java.rmi.server.UID, array length: -1, nRefs: 8, depth: 3, bytes: 283,
>   ex: n/a
>
> 15:37:07,422 DEBUG [serialization] ObjectInputFilter UNDECIDED: null,
>   array length: -1, nRefs: 10, depth: 1, bytes: 364, ex: n/a
>
> 15:37:07,422 DEBUG [serialization] ObjectInputFilter UNDECIDED: null,
>   array length: -1, nRefs: 11, depth: 2, bytes: 369, ex: n/a

I have no idea what that is. The most relevant information I found was at: https://dzone.com/articles/a-first-look-into-javas-new-serialization-filterin
which isn't very helpful. Anyone knows exactly what the logging mean and whether it may indicate an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by the new `ObjectInputFilter` class in Java 8. If there was a problem you would have had an exception. Just lower the log level to get rid of it.

Comment: I figured as much, but wanted to be sure. I actually do not see any documentation regarding this class in Java 8 JavaDoc (I see in in Java 9). Is it something "internal", like sun.* packages? Out of pure curiosity